# What is the difference in typescript between defining a method in the constructor or as a regular class method?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm migrating a angular 1 application from javascript to typescript. Actually everything is done but I can't get my head arround one specific case.

I have some directives that use a link function.

in pseudocode:

```
class SomeDirective implements ng.IDirective{
    static $inject=['someService'];
    public restrict: string='EA';
    public scope: any;
    constructor(private someService: SomeService){
        this.scope={
            data: '='
        }
    }
}
```

now I want to Define a link function like

```
public link(scope, ele, attrs){
     do some action with this.someService.someField
}
```

If I define this method in the class then I get an error: property 'someField' not found on undefined.

If I define the method as follows in the constructor then it does work. What is the difference?

```
this.link=(scope,ele,attrs)=>{
    do some action with this.someService.someField
}
```

link is defined here as a class property of type any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the function in the constructor creates, as you wrote, a class property, and it's assigned to the instance only.
A class method on the other hand is defined on the prototype:

```
class A {
    fn2: () => void;

    constructor() {
        this.fn2 = () => {
            console.log("A.fn2");
        };
    }

    fn1(): void {
        console.log("A.fn1");
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.fn2 = function () {
            console.log("A.fn2");
        };
    }
    A.prototype.fn1 = function () {
        console.log("A.fn1");
    };
    return A;
}());
```

Using the instance function is problematic if you want to override the function in a derived class:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.fn2 = () => {
            super.fn2(); // Error: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword
            console.log("B.fn2");
        };
    }

    fn1(): void {
        super.fn1();
        console.log("A.fn1");
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn2%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fn2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22A.fn2%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn1()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22A.fn1%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fn2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.fn2()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Only%20public%20and%20protected%20methods%20of%20the%20base%20class%20are%20accessible%20via%20the%20'super'%20keyword%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22B.fn2%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn1()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.fn1()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22A.fn1%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You can save a reference for the previous `this.fn2` before assigning the new function (in `B`) so that you'll have a super to call, but that isn't very comfortable.

The plus of course (if you're using arrow functions) is that the functions are bound to the right `this` out of the box.

It's up to you to decide what's more important to you, I prefer the methods way, and if I pass them as callbacks then I just [bind them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

---

#### Edit

The right `this` should always be correct when you invoke the methods regularly:

```
class A {
    bound: () => void;

    constructor() {
        this.bound = () => {
            console.log("bound: ", this);
        };
    }

    unbound(): void {
        console.log("unbound: ", this);
    }
}

let a1 = new A();
a1.bound(); // A {}
a1.unbound(); // A {}
```

As expected, `this` here is the instance of `A`, but:

```
function later(fn: Function) {
    setTimeout(fn, 100);
}

later(a1.bound); // A {}
later(a1.unbound); // Window { ... }
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bound%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bound%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22bound%3A%20%22%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unbound()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22unbound%3A%20%22%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Aa1.bound()%3B%20%2F%2F%20A%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aa1.unbound()%3B%20%2F%2F%20A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20later(fn%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(fn%2C%20100)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alater(a1.bound)%3B%20%2F%2F%20A%20%7B%7D%0D%0Alater(a1.unbound)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Window%20%7B%20...%20%7D))

As you can see here, when invoking `a1.unbound` using a `setTimeout` (or if you pass it as a callback) then `this` isn't the instance of `A`.
That can be fixed like so:

```
later(a1.unbound.bind(a1)); // A {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this extended explenation. Unfortunately it's still not entirely clear to me. When I define services or controllers in the same way (functions defined outside the constructor), the generated code also contains methods who are created on the prototype and where "this" references the instantiated class properties. In this case it seems like "this" in the link function is only scoped to the function itself and not the enclosing class.

Comment: Revised my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you! The problem here is that it is angular who calls the link function so it should execute the bind method but I don't think it does that. So I think it is best here to stay with the version that is created in the constructor.

Comment: You can have a class method (which is declared outside of the ctor) and then bind it in the ctor: `this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this)` and then you get to enjoy both worlds

Comment: Found this interesting [post](http://blog.aaronholmes.net/writing-angularjs-directives-as-typescript-classes/)